# Can you attack for percentile points if someone is already three starred?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Clash of clans...first time in a tie an wanted to be sure before I attack.

Answer (score 8):

No since a three star means the damage done is 100 percent. This means that your attack will be equal to or less than the damage done to that base thus not affecting the percentage. The percentage is based on damage dealt ***per base*** not per battle.

Answer (score 2):

No, if someone is 3☆'d, you cannot earn more stars out of them. You will earn a war loot bonus, however. (Kudo's to ModDL for that!)

Comment: You can still earn an war loot bonus if you at least 1 star it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker isn't interested in earning more stars, but in earning more destruction percentage in order to swing the tie-breaker into his/her favor.

Comment: @Ellesedil I believe it does answer the question. The answer is "no".